# Type deduction in C# generics like in C++ templates?

Tags: c#, c++, templates, generics

In C#: Is it possible to use a type of a generic argument class as return type for methods or to define members?

C++ Example:

```
class AgrumentClass
{
    typedef int type;
public:
    static type GetSomething() { return 0; }
};

template< class T >
class GenericClass
{
    typedef typename T::type type;
public:
    static type GetSomething() { return T::GetSomething(); }
};

int main()
{
    int value = GenericClass<AgrumentClass>::GetSomething();

    return value;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not code conversion tool !

Comment: yes it is possible you can learn c# generics and you can use them pretty much everywhere https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: @mybirthname He's not asking for a code conversion tool. He's asking if there's a parallel capability in C#, and including a C++ example to show the concept to which he is referring.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw okay if I write you an assembly code and ask if this is possible in c#, is it code conversion or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Your example as such does not have a clean translation to C#, because it makes an assumption about a method available on the generic type. C# allows you to restrict the generic type to descendants or implementers of a particular type or interface, but that's as far as you can go. If the method can't be resolved to the type at compile time, it won't compile.

Comment: I don't think there is for static methods. If I remember correctly, in C#, static methods are not inheritable.

Comment: static is not important - I used static only to make the C++ example as short and simple as possible (without object instantiations).